# Summarising column values from "S" to the next

Tags: r

I have multiple data frames that looks like this (shortened):

```
ref       perc_fragments rank_code scientific_name 
Sample1   73.43          S         Escherichia coli                  
Sample1   2.10           S1        Escherichia coli P12b             
Sample1   1.40           S2        Escherichia coli CFT073           
Sample1   0.70           S1        Escherichia coli O6:H16
Sample1   1.40           S         Klebsiella pneumoniae     
Sample1   0.70           S         Shigella dysenteriae      
Sample1   1.40           S         Staphylococcus aureus     
Sample1   1.40           S1        S. aureus xyz
```

What I want to do is to sum up the perc_fragments for all rows in the same group. The first `S` in the `rank_code` column starts the group, and all `S1` or `S2` after that is part of that group until a new `S` is met. In the case above, the first four rows are one group, then there are three rows with single-row groups, and the last two rows are one group. I want the scientific_name column to show the scientific_name of the `S` row for each group, with the sum of the `S` and all the `S1` in the same group. In other words, this:

```
ref       perc_fragments rank_code scientific_name 
Sample1   77.63          S         Escherichia coli                  
Sample1   1.40           S         Klebsiella pneumoniae     
Sample1   0.70           S         Shigella dysenteriae      
Sample1   2.8            S         Staphylococcus aureus
```

I have tried a few things, but a simple `grepl` won't work to group these together, as the `scientific_name` may be slightly different for the `S1` rows.

Testdata:

```
structure(list(ref = c("Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", 
"Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", 
"Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", 
"Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1"), perc_fragments = c("73.43", 
"2.10", "1.40", "0.70", "1.40", "0.70", "0.70", "0.70", "0.70", 
"0.70", "0.70", "0.70", "0.70", "0.70", "0.70", "1.40", "0.70", 
"0.70", "0.70", "1.40", "1.40"), rank_code = c("S", "S1", "S1", 
"S2", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", 
"S1", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S1"), scientific_name = c("Escherichia coli", 
"Escherichia coli P12b", "Escherichia coli O157:H7", "Escherichia coli O157:H7 str. SS17", 
"Escherichia coli CFT073", "Escherichia coli O6:H16", "Escherichia coli APEC IMT5155", 
"Escherichia coli UM146", "Escherichia coli C", "Escherichia coli ATCC 8739", 
"Escherichia coli FAP1", "Escherichia coli O27:H7", "Escherichia coli IAI1", 
"Escherichia coli O127:H6", "Escherichia coli PCN061", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", 
"Klebsiella variicola", "Citrobacter freundii", "Shigella dysenteriae", 
"Staphylococcus aureus", "Staphylococci haemolyticus"
)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(grp = cumsum(rank_code == 'S')) %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(perc_fragments = sum(perc_fragments)) %>% 
   filter(rank_code == 'S') %>% ungroup() %>% select(-grp)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ref     perc_fragments rank_code scientific_name      
  <chr>            <dbl> <chr>     <chr>                
1 Sample1           86.0 S         Escherichia coli     
2 Sample1            1.4 S         Klebsiella pneumoniae
3 Sample1            0.7 S         Klebsiella variicola 
4 Sample1            0.7 S         Citrobacter freundii 
5 Sample1            0.7 S         Shigella dysenteriae 
6 Sample1            2.8 S         Staphylococcus aureus
```

Comment: This was perfect, thanks for informing about `cumsum`!

Answer (score 1):

Use `cumsum` to create new groups whenever `'S'` is encountered in `rank_code` column and `sum` the `perc_fragments` values in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ref, grp = cumsum(rank_code == 'S')) %>%
  summarise(perc_fragments = sum(as.numeric(perc_fragments)), 
            across(c(rank_code, scientific_name), first)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)

#   ref     perc_fragments rank_code scientific_name      
#  <chr>            <dbl> <chr>     <chr>                
#1 Sample1           86.0 S         Escherichia coli     
#2 Sample1            1.4 S         Klebsiella pneumoniae
#3 Sample1            0.7 S         Klebsiella variicola 
#4 Sample1            0.7 S         Citrobacter freundii 
#5 Sample1            0.7 S         Shigella dysenteriae 
#6 Sample1            2.8 S         Staphylococcus aureus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum(x$rank_code == "S")` to `split` into the wanted groups.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, cumsum(x$rank_code == "S")), function(y) {
  z <- y[1,]
  z$perc_fragments <- sum(y$perc_fragments)
  z
}))
#      ref perc_fragments rank_code       scientific_name
#1 Sample1          77.63         S      Escherichia coli
#2 Sample1           1.40         S Klebsiella pneumoniae
#3 Sample1           0.70         S  Shigella dysenteriae
#4 Sample1           2.80         S Staphylococcus aureus
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ref       perc_fragments rank_code scientific_name 
Sample1   73.43          S         'Escherichia coli'
Sample1   2.10           S1        'Escherichia coli P12b'
Sample1   1.40           S2        'Escherichia coli CFT073'
Sample1   0.70           S1        'Escherichia coli O6:H16'
Sample1   1.40           S         'Klebsiella pneumoniae'
Sample1   0.70           S         'Shigella dysenteriae'
Sample1   1.40           S         'Staphylococcus aureus'
Sample1   1.40           S1        'S. aureus xyz'")
```